# Book about female main character named Juniper

Tags: story-identification, novel

I read the sci-fi or fantasy book probably around 1992, having gotten it from my junior high school's library. All I can remember about it is that the main character was a teenage female named Juniper. Her mom had named her after the tree. She had a male best friend. I believe she also liked painting.

Comment: This question doesn't appear to be about science fiction or fantasy

Comment: @Valorum I concede that you could be right. But since I only read sci-fi/fantasy books, this seemed the logical place to post. Was hoping others may have known what it was.

Comment: [The Juniper Game](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/118768.The_Juniper_Game)?

Comment: [Juniper, Gentian and Rosemary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Juniper,_Gentian,_and_Rosemary)? Though it's late 90's and Gentian is the main character...

Comment: @JohnRennie: This is it! OMG. Now that I'm seeing it, that cover is what reminded me.

Comment: It's been identified and the book IS SF, as it has telepathy as a plotpoint. So I'm voting to reopen.

Comment: @JohnRennie: It is reopened. Do you wish to post that as an answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The book is [The Juniper Game](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/118768.The_Juniper_Game) by Sherryl Jordan. It was published in 1991, which fits with you reading it in 1992.

[image: The Juniper Game]

*Juniper* is the teenage girl, and her male friend is *Dylan*. Once she discovers Dylan can receive telepathic communications from her she embarks on experiments with him that take a dark turn.

Comment: Thank you so much! This was definitely it.